# swift open custom popup only if closed

Tags: swift, popupwindow

i have a popup, which i'm calling like this:

```
if !MainView.isOpen.isPopupOpen{
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
            MainView.isOpen.init(isPopupOpen: true)
                var popOverVc = UIStoryboard(name: "CreateSurvey", bundle: 
  nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "greatPopup") as! PopupViewController
                   self.addChild(popOverVc)
                                  popOverVc.view.frame = self.view.frame
                                  self.view.addSubview(popOverVc.view)
                                  popOverVc.didMove(toParent: self)
            }
    }
}
```

I cannot check if its false because xcode is saying: Instance member 'isPopupOpen' cannot be used on type 'MainView.isOpen'
i have tried to get the current state using a struct but this didn't work out. Here is my Struct:

```
  struct  isOpen {
  var isPopupOpen: Bool!
}
```

and here is how i'm trying to change the value of my struct in the popup viewcontroller:

```
@IBAction func removeAnimation(_ sender: Any) {
    MainView.isOpen.init(isPopupOpen: false)
    removeAnimate()
}
```

is there any other way to solve the issue to open the popup only when its closed or how can i fix this issue?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the view's subviews contains the view/view controller you have added. It could be achieved in this way:

```
if self.view.subviews.contains(myView) == false {
  // Open popup since it is closed, not presented in the view
  // Or, in your case self.children.contains(popupView)
} else {
  // Do Nothing
}
```